# Does the verb "verlieren" require a preposition?

Tags: preposition, usage, grammaticality

Why in the following sentence

> Die beiden großen Parteien verloren **an** Stimmen, während die kleineren Parteien Stimmen gewinnen konnten.

is there a preposition in the main clause only? Does *verlieren* require a preposition while the opposite (i.e. *gewinnen*) does not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nein. Man könnte genausogut sagen:

> Die großen Parteien verloren Stimmen.

Answer (score 4):

Nein, dieses *»an«* ist optional, wird im Allgemeinen aber nur dann verwendet, wenn statt des Ganzen lediglich ein Teil verloren wird.

> Gegenüber der letzten Wahl verlor die Partei [an] Stimmen.

In Ausnahmefällen kann das *»an«* auch dann verwendet werden, wenn das Gesamte verloren wird. Dies muss dann aber ausdrücklich aus dem Satz hervorgehen.

> Gegenüber der letzten Wahl verlor die Partei an Stimmen alles, was sie hatte.

Answer (score 1):

No. Consider "Du verlierst die Partie." or "Sie verloren meine Stimme."